# Slow query with HAVING clause - can I speed it up?

Tags: mysql, performance, having

I have the following query which produces the expected results but is very slow (it takes about 10 seconds. The gstats table has about 130k rows in my development environment and is much bigger in production):

```
SELECT count(d.id) AS dcount, s.id, s.name
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN deals d ON (s.id = d.site_id AND d.is_active = 1)
WHERE (s.is_active = 1)
AND s.id IN(
    SELECT g.site_id
    FROM gstats g
    WHERE g.start_date > '2015-04-30'
    GROUP BY g.site_id
    HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
)
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY dcount ASC
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I speed this up?

Would adding indexes/using a view help?

Comment: Can you add an `explain` before the query, execute and share the results with us?
It shows the query execution plan and tells you where it's using index and where not and how many rows are scanned etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be to *filter* in the subquery:

```
SELECT count(d.id) AS dcount, s.id, s.name
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN deals d ON (s.id = d.site_id AND d.is_active = 1)
WHERE (s.is_active = 1)
AND s.id IN(
    SELECT g.site_id
    FROM gstats g
    WHERE g.start_date > '2015-04-30' AND g.site_id = s.id
    GROUP BY g.site_id
    HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
)
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY dcount ASC
```

Since otherwise, you do such grouping query for every possible candidate. We can make this more elegant with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT count(d.id) AS dcount, s.id, s.name
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN deals d ON (s.id = d.site_id AND d.is_active = 1)
WHERE (s.is_active = 1)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM gstats g
    WHERE g.site_id = s.id AND g.start_date > '2015-04-30'
    HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
)
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY dcount ASC
```

But we are not done yet, now we will use the `EXISTS` for *every* element. That's weird since the query only depends on `s.id`, so it only depends on the *group*, not the individual rows. So a *potential* speedup, but this depends on the sizes of the tables, etc. is to move the condition to a `HAVING` statement:

```
SELECT count(d.id) AS dcount, s.id, s.name
FROM sites s
LEFT JOIN deals d ON (s.id = d.site_id AND d.is_active = 1)
WHERE (s.is_active = 1)
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY dcount ASC
HAVING EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM gstats g
    WHERE g.site_id = s.id AND g.start_date > '2015-04-30'
    HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
)
```

Comment: thank you :) this worked perfectly, it now takes something like 30ms on my dev environment - out of curiosity: what if I wanted to also SELECT that sum(g.results) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT count(d.id) AS dcount, s.id, s.name
FROM sites s JOIN
     (SELECT g.site_id
      FROM gstats g
      WHERE g.start_date > '2015-04-30'
      GROUP BY g.site_id
      HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
     ) g
     ON g.site_id = s.site_id LEFT JOIN
     deals d
     ON s.id = d.site_id AND d.is_active = 1
WHERE s.is_active = 1
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY dcount ASC;
```

I assume you have indexes on the `join` columns.  You might also find that this helps performance:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM deals d
        WHERE d.site_id = s.id AND d.is_active = 1
       ) as dcount
FROM sites s JOIN
     (SELECT g.site_id
      FROM gstats g
      WHERE g.start_date > '2015-04-30'
      GROUP BY g.site_id
      HAVING SUM(g.results) > 100
     ) g
     ON g.site_id = s.site_id 
WHERE s.is_active = 1
ORDER BY dcount ASC;
```

For this version, you want an index on `deals(site_id, is_active)`.

Comment: this would be the correct answer, too. it works for me, but I'm using Doctrine which does not support a JOIN statement with a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine as is. I suggest the following indexes:

```
create index idx_gstats on gstats(start_date, results, site_id);
create index idx_deals1 on deals(is_active, site_id);
create index idx_deals2 on deals(site_id, is_active);
```

Then see the execution plan for the query and remove the deals index that doesn't get used.