# How to speed up a SQL query with HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, having

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.amount_limit
     , SUM( t.amount ) AS approved 
  FROM table_transactions AS t
     , table_users AS u 
 WHERE t.uid = u.id 
   AND t.status = 1 
   AND u.status = 1 
   AND u.amount_limit != 0 
 GROUP 
    BY t.uid 
 HAVING approved >= u.amount_limit
```

In a database with 1000 users and 1000000 transactions, it take about 7-8 seconds.

There is a way to optimize / speed up this sql query?

PS: I need the **amount** and the **number of users that reached the limit**, which I currently get with PHP mysql_num_rows().

**UPDATE: HERE IS THE TABLES STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_users (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `amount_limit` float DEFAULT NULL,
   ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_transactions` (
  `id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023382/slow-query-with-having-clause-can-i-speed-it-up

Comment: First, you need to write a query that makes sense.  You have `SELECT` columns that have nothing to do with the `GROUP BY` columns; you have unaggregated columns in the `HAVING`.  The arcane `JOIN` syntax doesn't affect the logic, but it looks quite awkward.

Comment: Add table definitions so we don't have to guess what indexes are in place and and explain plan.

Comment: Pls include the create table statements for the relevant tables, as well as the output of the explain of the sql query.

Comment: added the tables structure as per your suggestion

Comment: Grouping by t.uid doesn't make a lot of sense to me - you may get a bunch of limits but no idea who they apply to.

Comment: Without "GROUP BY t.uid" the query doesn't work unfortunately, if you have a better solution I'm all ears. thanks

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

```
SELECT  u.amount_limit, x.approved
    FROM ( SELECT  uid, SUM(amount) AS approved
            FROM  transactions
            WHERE  status = 1
         ) AS x
    JOIN  users AS u  ON u.id = x.uid
    WHERE  u.amount_limit != 0
      AND  u.status = 1
      AND  x.approved >= u.amount_limit
```

Plan B, possibly faster if a lot of users have limit=0 or status != 1:

```
SELECT  u.amount_limit, 
        ( SELECT  SUM(amount) AS approved
            FROM  transactions
            WHERE  status = 1
              AND  uid = u.id 
        ) AS approved
    FROM  users AS u
    WHERE  u.amount_limit != 0
      AND  u.status = 1
      AND  approved >= u.amount_limit
```

Both would benefit from these composite indexes:

```
users:        INDEX(status, amount_limit, id)
transactions: INDEX(status, uid, amount)
```

If `id` and `uid` are "random" number like UUIDs or hashes, access will be random and slow.  The indexes I provided will be "covering" thereby compensating significantly for the problem.

Suggest you rethink the design of the ids.

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` should be avoided for monetary values.  See `DECIMAL(m,n)`, instead.

Indexing a 'flag' (such as `status`) by itself is rarely useful.  Having it as a part of a composite index is may be useful.